# Anchor tag wont work

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why my `<a href>` tag wont work. I have the exact same tag at the top of my page in a `<ul>` and it works perfectly. When I copied and pasted(also tried re-typing) the exact same line in a `<div>` further down, it doesnt work. The encapsulated text just turns purple.

The code around the `<a>` tag is structured as follows:

```
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--deep" >

    <label> Some Text</label>

        <div style="position: absolute;
                left: 30%;
                width: 70%;
                margin-top: 10%;">

                <p style="position: absolute;
                            text-align:center; 
                            border-right: 2px solid #484848;
                            line-height: 125%;
                            color: #484848;
                            width: 70%;
                            font-family: sf_regular;">

                  This the paragraph <br>
                  <b>I want to insert</b>
                  a link in.

                  <br><br>
                  <img src="some_image.png" width = "70px" length = "70px"/>
                  <br><br>

                  <a href="#group5"> This Link </a> wont work!

                  </p>              

        </div>

</div>

<div id="group5" class="parallax__group">


  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
    This is group 5
  </div>

</div>
```

**The `<ul>` that works just fine(its not in any `<div>` by the way):**

```
 <nav>
 <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#group1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group2">Features</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group3">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group4">C2A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#group5">Contact Us</a></li>

 </ul>
 </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parallax {
min-height: 600px; /* fallback for older browsers */
height: 100vh;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
-webkit-perspective: 300px;
perspective: 300px;
perspective-origin-x: 100%;
}

.parallax__group {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 600px; /* fallback for older browsers */
 height: 100vh;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax__layer {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 transform-origin-x: 100%;
 }

 .parallax__layer--fore {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  z-index: 1;
  }

 .parallax__layer--base {linking works fine from here
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
  }

  .parallax__layer--back {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
   transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
   z-index: 2;
   }

  .parallax__layer--deep {//group with problematic link
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
   transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
   z-index: 2;
   }

  #group4 {//group with problematic link
    z-index: 2; /* slide under group 3 and 5 */
   }

   #group4 .parallax__layer--deep {
   background: #f7f7f7
   }

 #group5 {
   z-index: 3; /* slide over group 4 and 6 */
  }

 #group5 .parallax__layer--base {
  background: #484848;
  }
```

That exact line with the `<a>` tag works perfectly fine at the beginning of the page. What am I missing?

**P.S: Im new to web dev**, but I'm pretty sure the nesting of my elements doesn't violate an W3C principles.

Comment: What do you mean `does not work`? If you can't click on it, than check if you don't have some other element atop of `<a>` (right-click > inspect - must highlight `<a>`, not some other element

Comment: You haven't associated "#group5" to any part in the given HTML Code.

Comment: It wont link to `#group5`, its just not clickable. Even when i hover over it, it doesnt show the url at the bottom left corner(FireFox). When i inspect element, it highlights the `<a>` tag just fine, and i did verify that `group5` exists.

Comment: @AnkitShubham , please see edit

Comment: @Justinas, please see edit.

Comment: If you are unable to click on it, then it's possible some CSS you are using are causing the element to be covered by another element. You need to supply the relevant CSS to check for that issue.

Comment: perhaps the div is already view able on the screen when you click the link - therefore it wouldn't do anythink

Comment: @Rob, please see edits. All my z-index values are positive.

Comment: @Toxide82, i guarantee you that is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that another element is placed on top of your link? That would explain why it doesn't show the url when hovering it.
You said, you're able to inspect it - but are you also able to do a right-click on the link? If you do a right-click on the link and click on "Inspect element" (or similar), which element is selected in the dev tools?

Comment: your right. There are 2 divs ontop of the the containing div. I set their colours to transparent, but i cant remove them without losing the parallex effect. I tested this by putting the link in the top div and it worked fine. What do u suggest i do?

Comment: Well, the only way would be to adapt the z-indices (either statically in your css or while scrolling via JS).

Comment: Was tryna avoid that, but thanks, il go the JS route

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using parallax.js plugin which may let the anchor tag wont work.Try to remove parallax plugin.

Comment: Nope, Pure CSS solution. Linking works on top-most layers, but not the deepest one..

Comment: try add this css

.parallax__layer--deep {
    z-index: 5;
}